# Swipe Views inside a Tab, Android

Tags: android, view, tabs, fragment, swipe

I'm working on the Swipe Views example from the Android Developers. This>  http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/EffectiveNavigation.zip

And I'm trying to modify it by putting the CollectionDemoActivity.java in my second tab, so what I want it's in the second tab appears what in that Activity(CollectionDemo) should.

So basically I want to have Swipes Views inside my second tab. I'm a newbie on Android so I'm stucked with this...

I made a static class (my code it's at the bottom) named LocalesFragment, which return a Fragment, that should have the Tabs and the fragment beneath them.

THE PROBLEM: In my second tab appears just the tabs and not the Fragment that appears on the CollectionDemoActivity, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT> When I'm swiping between the tabs in my second Main Tab, just swipe till the third tab and 'disappears' the Tab Bar, I believe it's something about the three main Tabs and the Listener, but not sure what it is...

Here's part of my code, and the complete code it's at the bottom's link.

```
 public static class LocalesFragment extends Fragment{
    CollectionAdapter adaptador;
    ViewPager miViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_collection_demo, container, false);

        adaptador = new CollectionAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        miViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        miViewPager.setAdapter(adaptador);

        return rootView;
    } 

     public static class CollectionAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

         String[] categoriasLocales = { "Todos", "Alimentos", "Cine", "Comida", "Ropa", "Videojuegos" };
            private int size = categoriasLocales.length;

            public CollectionAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                Fragment fragment = new misFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(misFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return size;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return categoriasLocales[position];
            }
     }

        public static class misFragment extends Fragment {

            public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
                Bundle args = getArguments();
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                        Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
                return rootView;
            }
        }
}
```

Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/38b070380b50426feab8#file-mainactivity-java

I hope somebody can help me out, sorry for my english btw...